# JQuery, Copy ASP.Net Image to HTML Image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image

I've got an ASP.Net app that uses Jquery ajax to get dynamic html an insert into a certain div on the screen. This works but one of the tags is an image tag and no image is being displayed, just the "X" since image is on the server. The path of the image is on the server, ~/Images/user2.png.

I'm thinking about having a server side image, , hold the image i need that is not visible and somehow using jquery, "copy" that image to the real html image tag after it is appended.
But I can't think of how to copy it.
The thing to remember is the html image tag doesn't exist until the ajax data is loaded and appended to the destination tag.

Ideas?

Comment: That tilde in the src attribute won't work with html as it'd a .net convention. Use an absolute or virtual path e.g   /Images/user2.png. or  ../Images/user2.png

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET tags turn into HTML tags best way for jquery is to add `Class="jqImgHandle"` then on your jQuery use

```
var src = $("jqImgHandle").attr('src');
```

then do what you want with source

Ok just incase your end user cant access the file

base64_encode the file

and set your source to `data:image/png;base64,{base64_code_here}` replace {base64_code_here} with your base 64 code

Comment: i got the source, but how do i make the image actually display?

Comment: sorry you lost me if you got the source just place it into your new image tag,

Comment: $(".UserImageClass").attr("src", $('#<%=ImageUser.ClientID%>').attr("src"));
                        alert($(".UserImageClass").attr("src"));

Comment: is your image in that file path try browsing to the image path

Comment: if so is your server setup to support PNG's or has some one removed it from the IIS Server?

Comment: yes, i made the server image visible and i can see it, it is part of the project and used elsewhere

Comment: @Barkermn01, the browser doesn't have rights to go there. plus the path is relative, ~/Images/user2.png.

Comment: SB_Table.Append("<img id='User' src=data:image/png;base64," + Base64EncodeFile("~/Images/user2.png") + "/>");

private static string Base64EncodeFile(string Path)
        {            
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
            return encodedData;
        }

Comment: What browser are you using IE7+ supports base64 encoding can you show me the end result use patebin so once your code has run i need the full source

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish but if you want to alter the src attribute of the image loaded after your ajax post..

```
//Your ajax post
$(".someSelector").append(data);
$("img.LoadedViaAjax").attr("src", $("img.hidden").attr("src"));
//The rest of your processing....
```

**update**

If the src you are setting the image to is valid it should pull in the image correctly.  See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/qn8KW/) for an example that toggles between a bad image, valid image, and back to a bad image.

What does your src look like?  Does the path look valid?

**update**
try to do this so you generate the absolute path instead of the relative one.

```
<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/imgxx.png")%>" />
```

Comment: i can copy the src from one to the other but the image isn't displayed, just the X

Comment: ~/Images/user2.png, it is part of the project and used elsewhere

Comment: i even made the server asp image tag visible and i can see it when the page loads

Comment: @Mark, you say if the src is valid it should pull the image, but the page has already loaded, ajax and jquery fire after that. How wold the page pull the image without going back to the server?

Comment: The document will see the url for the src has changed and make a request for the image. .../something/user2.png

Comment: @Mark, when i try ReolveURL the src becomes ../../Images/user2.png and no image is displayed